# Convert SQL Server varbinary field to string?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a column in a sql server 2005 database that stores xml as varbinary,
the value lookes something like:

```
0x3C3F54657374696E672075706C6F616 // but much longer
```

Is there an online conversion tool for converting this to a readable string?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
select CAST(0x3C3F54657374696E672075706C6F61643F3E3C666F6F3E3C2F666F6F3E as XML)
```

appears to work.

[Online Conversion Link](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/98094/)

And as it seems your datatype is `image`...

```
;with t(c) as
(
select CAST(0x3C3F54657374696E672075706C6F61643F3E3C666F6F3E3C2F666F6F3E as IMAGE)

)
select CAST(CAST(c as VARBINARY(MAX)) as XML)
from t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the undocumented stored procedure.

```
SELECT fn_varbintohexstr(@YourVarbar)
```

You should also be able to just cast it to a varchar(max) as well

```
Select CAST(@YourVarbar as Varchar(max))
```

Third alternative is to create an XML document out of it and use forXML
Example at the following location http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/jacob/archive/2009/06/13/converting-varbinary-to-varchar-using-for-xml.aspx

```
    DECLARE @x VARBINARY(10)
    SELECT  @x = CAST('10' as VARBINARY(10))
    SELECT @x AS VarBinaryValue
    SELECT (
    SELECT 
        CHAR(SUBSTRING(@x,number,1)) AS 'text()'
    FROM master..spt_values 
    WHERE type = 'P'
        AND Number BETWEEN 1 AND LEN(@x)    
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ) AS TextValue
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks, I tried with your first example and got "Explicit conversion from data type image to varchar(max) is not allowed."